# Meteor login and logout are slow

Tags: performance, authentication, meteor, logout, subscription

My subscriptions download a lot of data for current user. I'm OK if these subscriptions are loaded in whatever order and time they please. When the user is already logged in, subscriptions load non-blockingly; that is, I can detect that Meteor.user() is present, display a template that gets progressively populated by incoming data. But when the user is not logged in, and initiates login, the Meteor.user() only appears when *all* subscriptions have finished loading.

The desired behavior is to get Meteor.user() as soon as login really occurs, not when all data is already here.

I've digged the source and found these comments:

```
  // This callback is called once the local cache of the current-user
  // subscription (and all subscriptions, in fact) are guaranteed to be up to
  // date.
  var loggedInAndDataReadyCallback = function (error, result) {
```

Does that mean that waiting for all subscriptions to load is hardcoded? Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 4):

Try delaying subscriptions until they are actually needed. For example:

```js
Tracker.autorun(function() {
  if (Meteor.user()) {
    Meteor.subscribe('expensiveSubscription');
  }
});
```

This won't activate the `expensiveSubscription` until the user is already logged in. You may not be able to do this with all of your subscriptions, but in general this is a good performance technique and may solve your problem.

Comment: No, this is solving the wrong problem. I need to get Meteor.user() right after login occurs, before subscriptions are loaded. But I do not need to block subscriptions loading. These are really different things.

Comment: Yes, my suspicion was that your subscriptions were preventing the user document from being sent. If the two could be loaded strictly serially then perhaps it could solve your problem. But this was just a guess - it was a little hard to figure out the exact requirements from the way the question was phrased. For example, if it's critical that all of your subscriptions be activated prior to login then this doesn't help.